# One user is getting Add and Delete buttons but another is not on related lists

Tags: apex, visualforce, profile, related-list

I have two users have both have different profiles. I am working on opportunity page and both the users are able to see "Opportunity Team" related list but one user can also Add and Delete the teams but another is not getting these Add and Delete options.

I tried but could not resolved the issues. Can anyone know how should i debug the issue? what settings should i check?

thanks in advance

Comment: Most likely they have different profile, one of which has the permissions needed to edit & delete opp. team records. Check the object permissions for both profiles and you'll probably see a difference.

Comment: Can you post your code ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The User who sees the Add / Delete buttons is prolly the [Opportunity Owner or above them in the Role Hierarchy](http://na9.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesteam_add.htm).

> To add team members to an opportunity:    “Read” on opportunities AND
>   Owner of opportunity record, or above owner in your organization's
>   role hierarchy

Comment: user has "Read" permission on Opportunity and he is owner of record as well. but still can't see ADD,Delete buttons. He has Create, Read, Edit and View all permissions on Opportunity objects but still not able to see the buttons but if i select "Modify All"  permission as well then he can see the buttons. i don't know why previously he was not able to see